# How can I get an alert when a specific post appears in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

When The Hungarian Opera House has a new promo, a post appears on its page
https://www.facebook.com/Operahaz/?ref=ts&fref=ts
and the first 10-50 people who click and answer a simple question get free tickets, I mean real tickets worth about 20 USD. The problem is this quota is reached in minutes. The post contains a link to an app:

https://www.facebook.com/Operahaz/app/167524726777735/

So, can I set up somehow an alert which notifies me when this post appear? Playing a sound, popping a message, sending an email, sms or any other way would be great.